# Как лучше хранить данные о пользователе с каждой группы телеграм?

Tags: python, mysql, mariadb

У меня есть база данных, раньше хранил данные с КАЖДОЙ группы о пользователе(т.е в одной группе у него 5 сообщений всего, в одной 10, и этих груп у него много) `Таблица > Столбец > JSON(словарь)` и если нужно извлечь какое-то значение я брал весь словарь и итерацией перебирал, и это слижком много лишнего кода, да и на обновление сотни пользователей и добавление новых строк в их словари это очень много времени, и возник вопрос - Как правильно и быстрее всего хранить информацию о пользователе с каждой группы? Чтобы быстро извлекать, легче обновлять столбцы или какие-то новые значения, и добавлять например новые столбцы одни мигом у всех пользователей?

P.S - делаю бота телеграм на python и mariadb

Comment: Почитайте что-нибудь о нормальных формах. И потом сделайте в соответствии с теорией.

Comment: Прочитав пару статей, я не нашел чего нибудь такого что реально помогло.. Но в голову мне пришла идея, но я боюсь что это слижком просто и возможно более памяти требует, если создать таблицу и в ней хранить информацию про пользователя группы, каждая группа в которой состоит пользователь - 1 ряд, возможно это плохой метод?